# How to alternativly ng-repeat elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having two tables (with tables inside)

```
table1 = [[a,a,a], [b,b,b], [c,c,c]];
table2 = [[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3]];
```

And I want to render an HTML table with ng-repeats (or something else), like that :

```
a | a | a
---------
1 | 1 | 1
---------
b | b | b
---------
2 | 2 | 2 etc ...
```

I can't figure out how to do this.

Thanks !

Comment: i will first merge the tow arrays then write che view code for that

Comment: @fantarama, Thanks that's working for me. Was quite simple but couldn't think of it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First merge the tables in the controller:

```
var table1 = [['a','a','a'], ['b','b','b'], ['c','c','c']];
var table2 = [[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3]];

$scope.table = [];

for (var i = 0; i < table1.length; i++) {
  $scope.table.push(table1[i]);
  $scope.table.push(table2[i]);
}
```

The use a nested `ng-repeat`. You will need to use `track by $index` as some of the items are the same.

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in table track by $index">
    <td ng-repeat="value in item track by $index">{{value}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XU7ZfDsx6nsktm5HDllJ?p=preview)